# Anylogic： How to use an agent's special connection number as a variable?

Tags: java, anylogic

I have an agent type `Household`, and its group `households`. They have a string variable `identity`, which will be dynamically assigned value at runtime, such as `"Volunteer"`, `"Initiator"`, and more.

Now I want to establish some special connections between the households. One of them is `neibNet`, which makes volunteers look for their nearest initiator. Then I want to read the **number of neibNet connections** existing on each initiator.

When I run the model, the problem is like [[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI8eO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/207HV.png). The connections have been applied successfully, the **number of neibNet connections** of each `Initiator` has been recorded and displayed, but I cannot reference this number to calculate `raisedDonation`.

I have tried following methods to get the value, they all returned 0:

```
// test 1, told by AI that it's the overall neibNet links rather than one agent
raisedDonation = this.neibNet.getConnectionsNumber() + 1;

// test 2
raisedDonation = this.neibNet.getConnections().size() +1;

// test 3
raisedDonation = this.neibNet.size() + 1;

// test 4
raisedDonation = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < main.households.size(); i++) {
    if (main.households.get(i).identity == "Volunteer") {
        int ii = i;
        Household raised = findFirst(main.households, h -> h.householdid == ii);
        if (raised.neibNet.isConnectedTo(this) == true) raisedDonation++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you clarify what you need? This is really unclear :)

Comment: @Benjamin Hi! I tried to describe more modelling concepts and coding. If it still doesn't seem clear enough, maybe you can give me a hint as to what details I should describe, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. The function `neibNet.getConnections().size()` or other similar methods CAN be used to read the number of special connections linking to a specific agent. However, I read the value while forming the connections, so the function has no time to catch a value. It is my logic fault.

Comment: thx for posting the solution, helps future folks with similar issues. Here aare some tips to improve future questions, happy to help: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow